# Magnetic circuit diagramming

Tags: coil, magnetics, core

What software makes magnetic circuit diagrams such as the one pictured?

[image]

Comment: I'd guess TikZ.

Comment: I appreciate your quick reply Sir. I was hoping Visio might be able to do it but the coil is what is vexing me...

Comment: It can be done with Visio, however, Tikz is much easier and the figure will be more neat. In Visio you will face difficulties in coil drawing and symbols.

Answer (score 4):

This looks like the [`winding` macro](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~aplevich/Circuit_macros/html/examples.html) of the [`Circuit_macros` pic/m4 package](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~aplevich/Circuit_macros/):

[image: The macro winding(L|R,diam,pitch,turns,core wid,core color)]

Comment: Your a good man CL, your guidance is most appreciated. Since I'm a FNG on the forum The Site will not let me upvote your most elucidating response...